# Assert\Range for integer doesn't work in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, assert

I want to validate an integer with `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints` to be in a special range.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = 120,
 *      max = 180,
 *      minMessage = "You must be at least 120 cm tall to enter",
 *      maxMessage = "You cannot be taller than 180 cm to enter"
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(name="cp",  type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $cp;
```

But it doesn't work.

Some info:

- This is in a custom UserEntity which extends BaseUser
- Symfony version 2.8
- I use easyAdminBundle to create/update/delete users
- I already put `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` at the top

Comment: Add information. Whent did you valid your entity after a form/ after a POST API ?

Comment: Did you add "use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert" at the top of your class?

Comment: I just add extra information, it's when I create a new user with easyAdminBundle
And yes I use the Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert at the top :/

Comment: Did you fill the form with a min value ? Remember that the RangeValidator doesn't validate a null value.

Comment: @Youri_G If I enter 1234 it pass the RangeValidator without any errors.When you said you fill the form with a min value you mean I should set the $cp = 0 in the constructor  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `validate()` method on the `validator` service.

Also check is your validation enabled in framework config.

When you want to persist new object you first validate them with `ValidatorInterface` instance method in your controller. If object is valid then persist them if not send user some info about error.

Please check full tutorial about use of `validator` and other stuff [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

If you use `easyAdminBundle` in config you must for `cp` property add

```
- { property: 'cp', type : 'integer', type_options: { attr : { min : minValue, max: maxValue }}}
```

Check documentation how to setup configuration fo [easy admin](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks it's perfect !